# Facebook app not visible to public not logged users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to understand why our app is not visible for users that are not logged to Facebook .

When you go to that app when you not logged in to dB for some reason you automatically get to the app page even when the url is apps. Facebook?? How can this be, this is not a PAGE url it's an app url.

https://apps.facebook.com/AYI

When i do the same with our app we get a block page with "unable to access", of the curse all public settings are ok and set in the app admin.

https://apps.facebook.com/fakeoff/

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Ever managed to find out what was the problem? I'm having the same issue and for the life of me, I can't figure out why the tab isn't displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps adding og tags to  fakeoff.me's html will work. Og tags let any site function as a facebook element. Check out www.ogp.me

Comment: Thanks, but the App page that load in the first example is not a web page, it's like there is a redirect from the web app to the app page. Can't find OG tags that do that.